# How many positive integers less than or equal to $2016$ cannot be expressed in the form $ n + s(n) $ for some positive integer $n$?

Tags: number-theory

For every positive integer $n$, let $s(n)$ denote the number of terminal zeroes in the decimal rep-
resentation of $n!$. For example,$ 10! = 3, 628, 800$ ends in two zeroes, so $s(10) = 2$. How many
positive integers less than or equal to $2016$ cannot be expressed in the form $n + s(n)$ for some
positive integer $n$?

$5, 11, 17, 23, 29, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 61, 62, ...$

The numbers above are the integers that cannot be expressed in the form and after some listing and some trial and error, I concluded every sixth integer after $29$ has a difference of $1$ with the following integer and then continues having a difference of $6$.

I then grouped them as follows...
$5 - 29$,
$30 - 60$,
$61 - 91$
      ...

I then noticed an arithmetic sequence starting from $60$ and then I added $5$ because I didn't count the numbers from $5 - 29$. My answer is $389$; is there anything wrong with my solution?

Comment: Are you saying that you computed a few values, noticed a pattern, and  then guessed that it will continue?  That's all well and good, but it's not a solution unless you *prove* that the pattern continues.

Comment: Hint: the number of $0$s in $n!$ is exactly the highest power of $5$ that divides $n!$.

Comment: Also, note that $n+s(n)$ is a strictly increasing sequence for $n$, if $N$ is the largest number such that $N + s(N) \leq 2016$, then the answer should be $2016 - N$.